# Shiny : keep the value in the mainpanel

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

This app shows a radiobutton choice between 3 lists : lower, upper, digit items

To test it, save the following code below in a directory "shiny" and in an app.R file. Then launch R and type :

```
library(shiny
runApp("shiny")
```

Default choice is lower list.

A sentence "select or type an item" appears in the choice list, thanx to the placeholder option.

If I choose an item in this list like "a", the choosed item appears in the mainpanel on the right.

If I change the kind of list says digit, a new choice list appears with digits as choice.

BUT the first item choosed "a" disappears from the mainpanel on the right.

If I choose the digit "2" it appears in the mainpanel on the right.

The issue is that I want to keep the choosed item in the mainpanel even if I change the kind of list with the radiobutton.

I don't understand why this choice disappears because in the oberveEvent of the radiobutton the rval reactiveValues don't change.

```
library(shinyjs)

ui <-fluidPage(
     useShinyjs(),
     id = "page",
    sidebarLayout(position = "left",
      sidebarPanel(
        radioButtons(
          "choice_btn", "Choose list:",
          c("Lower" = "lower", "Upper" = "upper", "Digit" = "digit"),
          selected="lower"
        ),
        selectizeInput(
          inputId="lower_choice",
          label="List of lower items",
          choices=NULL,
          selected=NULL,
          options = list(placeholder='select or type an item')
        ),
        selectizeInput(
          inputId="upper_choice",
          label="List of upper items",
          choices=NULL,
          selected=NULL,
          options = list(placeholder='select or type an item')
        ),
        selectizeInput(
          inputId="digit_choice",
          label="List of digit items",
          choices=NULL,
          selected=NULL,
          options = list(placeholder='select or type an item')
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        textOutput("item")  
      )
    )
  )    

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rval <- reactiveVal()

  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'lower_choice', choices = c("a","b","c","d"), selected = character(0), server = TRUE)
  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'upper_choice', choices = c("A","B","C","D") , selected = character(0), server = TRUE)
  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'digit_choice', choices = c(1,2,3,4) , selected = character(0), server = TRUE)
  
  shinyjs::hide("upper_choice")
  shinyjs::hide("digit_choice")
  output$item <- renderText({ rval() })
  
  observeEvent(input$choice_btn, {
    choice  <- input$choice_btn
    choices <- c("lower", "upper", "digit")
    shinyjs::show(paste0(choice,"_choice"))
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'lower_choice', choices = c("a","b","c","d"), selected = character(0), server = TRUE)
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'upper_choice', choices = c("A","B","C","D"), selected = character(0), server = TRUE)
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'digit_choice', choices = c(1,2,3,4), selected = character(0), server = TRUE)
    for (x in choices) {
      if ( x != choice ) {
        shinyjs::hide(paste0(x,"_choice"))
        }
    }
    
  })
 
  observeEvent(input$lower_choice, {
    rval(input$lower_choice)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$upper_choice, {
    rval(input$upper_choice)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$digit_choice, {
    rval(input$digit_choice)
  })
  
# end shinyServer   
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO the issue is that all of your `selectizeInput`s are updated when the user switches the type of list. And as a consequence the selected value is for each `selectizeInput` is set to an empty string `""`. Accordingly the `observeEvent` for the selected list is triggered and the `reactiveVal` gets updated with an empty string which is what the `textInput` displays.

One option to prevent that would be to add an `if` statement to each of your `observeEvent`s to update the `reactiveVal` only when the user made a choice, i.e. when the choice is different from an empty string:

```
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  id = "page",
  sidebarLayout(
    position = "left",
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons(
        "choice_btn", "Choose list:",
        c("Lower" = "lower", "Upper" = "upper", "Digit" = "digit"),
        selected = "lower"
      ),
      selectizeInput(
        inputId = "lower_choice",
        label = "List of lower items",
        choices = NULL,
        selected = NULL,
        options = list(placeholder = "select or type an item")
      ),
      selectizeInput(
        inputId = "upper_choice",
        label = "List of upper items",
        choices = NULL,
        selected = NULL,
        options = list(placeholder = "select or type an item")
      ),
      selectizeInput(
        inputId = "digit_choice",
        label = "List of digit items",
        choices = NULL,
        selected = NULL,
        options = list(placeholder = "select or type an item")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("item")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rval <- reactiveVal()

  output$item <- renderText({
    rval()
  })

  observeEvent(input$choice_btn, {
    choice <- input$choice_btn
    choices <- c("lower", "upper", "digit")
    
    for (x in choices[!choices %in% choice]) {
      shinyjs::hide(paste0(x, "_choice"))
    }
    
    shinyjs::show(paste0(choice, "_choice"))
    
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'lower_choice', choices = c("a","b","c","d"), selected = character(0), server = TRUE)
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'upper_choice', choices = c("A","B","C","D"), selected = character(0), server = TRUE)
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'digit_choice', choices = c(1,2,3,4), selected = character(0), server = TRUE)
  })

  observeEvent(input$lower_choice, {
    if (input$lower_choice != "") rval(input$lower_choice)
  })

  observeEvent(input$upper_choice, {
    if (input$upper_choice != "") rval(input$upper_choice)
  })

  observeEvent(input$digit_choice, {
    if (input$digit_choice != "") rval(input$digit_choice)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx, yes I want to reset selectizeInputs when the user changes list because I want to clean their content and have the placeholder message. It works, thanx